# Reload browser page (and resources) entirely from cache

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, web-development, browser-cache

I'm currently working remote on a specific web project. Their VPN connection is quite unreliable, so it can be difficult to refresh a page because the database lies on one of their local machines.

At times, it's best to watch the execution of a page's JavaScript multiple times in a row. This can be incredibly time consuming and difficult on a slow connection.

Is it possible to refresh a page almost entirely from the browser's cache? (i.e. without making a request to the server again?) Basically, I'd like to replay the page load. The only way I know how to do this is if there is a way to pull all the resources from cache and reloading the page from that.

Is this possible?

Comment: This probably involves more recoding than you'd be willing to go through with, and is more of a programming-related solution, but offline manifests might be one possible solution, if you can gather all the necessary filenames into one file. http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html